# C# program to raise PC temperature

Tags: c#, angular, cpu, temperature, heat

I'm cold and want a C# program to best raise the PC temperature so fan outputs more heat but don't want windows to lock up.  I've looked for USB desk heaters but best I have found is a mug warmer.  Unfortunately boss's tight and do not allow personal heaters!

Comment: What kind of question is that? This kinda seems the wrong place and with this little info about architecture, nobody will be able to answer you how to fill up CPU utilization properly to get an optimal power-usage/heat.

Comment: Step 1: Disable Ad Block Plus. Step 2: find new job on the right side of stackoverflow website. Step 3: ??? Step 4: Profit.

Comment: Angular 2 documentation will surely raise your body's temperature

Comment: Calculate some prime numbers or pi.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a joke, not a question

Comment: Easy...just open embed a web browser control in say a Winforms app and navigate to _FaceBook_.

Comment: I used to run a program called "coat". That worked well until I found a better one called "new job": that one had better stuff like built-in heaters etc.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/86922/how-much-of-a-gpus-electrical-usage-is-probably-turned-into-a-increase-in-air-t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally used to run Graphics card bitcoin mining rigs, and later ASIC mining rigs to heat up my home (lived in a boat!) and worked wonders in the winter, save on heating costs and making money!

Now though you need very cheap electricity to run bitcoin miners to turn a profit.

Personally i think you should go for a pair of these https://www.amazon.co.uk/USB-Heating-Slippers-Comfort-Warming/dp/B005PJMGU8